# Install custom Behaviour in Expression Blend 4

Tags: expression-blend, blend

I have Blend 4 installed and noticed that it didnt include a GoToNextState or GoToPrevState behaviour by default.

I have been given a DLL called GotoStateActions, but i dont know what to do with it.

This should include the missing states, but how do i 'install' them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.johnstagich.com/Blog/post/Add-a-behavior-that-was-created-by-someone-else.aspx